# Collapse indented bulleted lists in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I often make bulleted lists like this:

```
- Heading 1
 - A point
 - Another point

- Heading 2
 - Subheading
  - some more stuff
```

I'd like to be able to collapse everything under a heading. Is this possible in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Possible in SynWrite editor, also free. Just click lexer statusbar field, call "Text with indentation" lexer.

Answer (score 1):

Select 'YAML' as the language for the file in question.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you explained how to get this functionality for files with extensions other then `.yml` ...